# Update rows in a summary table with min and max values from a related table using a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, concurrency, database-trigger

I have two tables, `Order` and `Slot`. Each slot has times, but for simplicity let's say they're integers. Something like this:

```
Order              Slot
-----              ----
order_id           slot_id
earliest           order_id
latest             time_from
                   time_to
```

I'm trying to keep `earliest` and `latest` updated such that `earliest = MIN(slot.time_from)` and `latest = MAX(time_to)`. It's always the case that `time_from < time_to`, but that shouldn't matter here.

To do this, I have created a trigger on UPDATE and INSERT on Slot. The trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION keep_orders_updated() RETURNS trigger AS $trigger$
BEGIN

  UPDATE "order"
  SET earliest=d.earliest_min, latest=d.latest_max
  FROM (SELECT MIN(time_from) as earliest_min, MAX(time_to) AS latest_max FROM "slot" WHERE order_id = NEW.order_id) AS d
  WHERE order_id=NEW.order_id;

  RETURN NULL;
END;
$trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER keep_orders_updated_trigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON "slot" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE keep_orders_updated();
```

It produces correct results in most cases, except in the following situation, which I'm trying to fix. We start with this data:

```
Order:
  order_id |   earliest    | latest     
 ----------+------------------------
     1     | 10            | 20


Slots:

  slot_id  | order_id | time_from   | latest         
 ----------+------------------------+------------------------
     1     | 1        | 10          | 12
     1     | 1        | 18          | 20
```

And in two concurrent transactions (in my case they are run using different connections from a connection pool in a web server, basically serving two requests arriving about at the same time):

```
tx1: UPDATE "slot" SET time_from=15 AND time_to=17;
tx2: UPDATE "slot" SET time_from=19 AND time_to=25;
```

I get the slots being updated correctly (expected), and the order updated wrongly. Only the latest updates:

```
Order:
  order_id |   earliest    | latest     
 ----------+------------------------
     1     | 10            | 25
```

Similarly, if I set the time_from to something smaller than 10, it updates.

I think I understand why this happens. Each slot update blocks on the relevant row allowing the updates to run concurrently. The trigger only sees the data its transaction updates, not what the other transaction updates. As a result, it computes MIN(10, 15) for tx1 and MIN(10, 19) for tx2 and sets earliest to 10 in the relevant order.

Is my understanding correct? How can such a config be made to work correctly?

Comment: I think I fixed it by selecting the all the slots FOR UPDATE before doing the update on order (`PERFORM slot_id FROM slot WHERE order_id=NEW.order_id FOR UPDATE`). Before this I tried to use an advisory lock using the order_id of the slots but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing this derived information, why not just create a view?

```
create view v_orders as
select order_id, min(time_from) earlierst, max(time_to) latest
from slots
group by order_id
```

With this technique, you don't need to worry about actually maintaining your data. The view provides an always up-to-date perspective at your data.

Comment: I work with a somewhat silly ORM (sqlboiler) that doesn't support views (at least not easily) and big part of the application revolves around orders and those dates. I also use the earliest and latest for different triggers (I need to know when they change - initially wrote this is doable but I'm not actually sure how to do it).

Comment: @VladV . . . How could the ORM not support views?  You can define the view in the database and the ORM should just see a read-only table.

Comment: I know it's odd. It generates code based on the DB schema, and totally ignores views. There's even [a $100 bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/40547862-generate-types-for-views) for someone [to implement that](https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/issues/54). I can, of course, use them manually.

Comment: Ignoring the ORM, is there a way to detect when `earliest` changes in this setup? I currently use a trigger on order update for that.